# How to plot polynomial regression line

Tags: regression, line

I'm having trouble plotting the regression line. Here is the code and my plot so far. I wanted to see the regression line between the points. Appreciate the help. I'm trying to do this in Python. Forgive my code, I'm a newb at this.

```
data = https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/blood-transfusion/
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x = df.iloc[:, 2:3]
y= df.iloc[:, -1]

x_train = np.array(x[:-20])
x_test = np.array(x[-20:])

y_train = np.array(y[:-20])
y_test = np.array(y[-20:])

for i in range(1,11):
    poly_regr = PolynomialFeatures(degree = i)
    x_train_poly = poly_regr.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test_poly = poly_regr.fit_transform(x_test)
    
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train_poly, y_train)
      
    
    train_pred = clf.predict(x_train_poly)
    test_pred = clf.predict(x_test_poly)
    
    train_error = (mean_squared_error(y_train, train_pred))
    test_error = (mean_squared_error(y_test, test_pred))
    
    x_axis = np.arange(0,10,.1)
    
    plt.scatter(i, train_error, color='green')
    plt.scatter(i, test_error, color='black')
    plt.grid(True)


for i in range(1,11):
    clf = Lasso(alpha = i)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
    train_pred = clf.predict(x_train)
    test_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
    
    train_error = (mean_squared_error(y_train, train_pred))
    test_error = (mean_squared_error(y_test, test_pred))

    x_axis = np.arange(0,10)

    plt.scatter(i, train_error, color='red')
    plt.scatter(i, test_error, color='brown')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0lLF.png)

I'd like to see the regression line.

Comment: Take a look at this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

Comment: This is actually the code that I patterned mine from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two plots, train and test on one plot. I assume that there will be two regression lines for both of them; one for train and one for test.

I suggest you put the errors in a list/array and add the plotting outside the loop. This will help you to use `np.polyfit` to find the slope and intercept which will help in plotting.

P.S. I used the `train_test_split()` so the plot looks a bit different

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('transfusion.data', sep=',', names=['R', 'F', 'M', 'T', 'class'])
df = df.drop(0)
df = df.astype('int32')

X = df.drop('class', axis=1)
y = df['class']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=27)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# initialize tr and te arrays for storing training and testing 
# accuracies respectively

### Linear Regression ###
tr = []
te = []

for i in range(1,11):
    poly_regr = PolynomialFeatures(degree = i)
    x_train_poly = poly_regr.fit_transform(X_train)
    x_test_poly = poly_regr.fit_transform(X_test)
    
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train_poly, y_train)
      
    
    train_pred = clf.predict(x_train_poly)
    test_pred = clf.predict(x_test_poly)
    
    train_error = (mean_squared_error(y_train, train_pred))
    tr.append(train_error)
    test_error = (mean_squared_error(y_test, test_pred))
    te.append(test_error)
    
x_axis = np.arange(1,11)

plt.scatter(x_axis, tr, color='green')
plt.scatter(x_axis, te, color='black')

m, b = np.polyfit(x_axis, tr, 1)
plt.plot(x_axis, m*x_axis+b)

m, b = np.polyfit(x_axis, te, 1)
plt.plot(x_axis, m*x_axis+b)

plt.grid(True)

### Lasso ###
tr = []
te = []
for i in range(1,11):
    clf = Lasso(alpha = i)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    train_pred = clf.predict(X_train)
    test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    
    train_error = (mean_squared_error(y_train, train_pred))
    tr.append(train_error)
    test_error = (mean_squared_error(y_test, test_pred))
    te.append(test_error)

x_axis = np.arange(1,11)

plt.scatter(x_axis, tr, color='red')
plt.scatter(x_axis, te, color='brown')

m, b = np.polyfit(x_axis, tr, 1)
plt.plot(x_axis, m*x_axis+b)

m, b = np.polyfit(x_axis, te, 1)
plt.plot(x_axis, m*x_axis+b)
```

Output for Linear Regression
[image]

And output for Lasso

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Creating a list is a lot easier to go! Thanks for helping out a newbie!